# Add metatool plugin to QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis-3

I downloaded the metatool plugin and copied `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\metatools` but when I open QGIS 3.0 it gives error the plugin is not compatible

Where can I get metatool plugin for QGIS 3.0?

Comment: Some plugins have not been updated for QGIS 3.0, so one option would be to install an older version of QGIS and use that instead.